# Notify MutableLiveData when another MutableLiveData value changes

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, observers, mutablelivedata

In my ViewModel I have the code shown below:

```
private val _sender = MutableLiveData<DialogListItem.ParticipantItem>()
val sender: LiveData<DialogListItem.ParticipantItem>
    get() = _sender

private val _receiverListItems: MutableLiveData<List<DialogListItem>> =
    CombinedLiveData<List<ParticipantTypeA>, List<ParticipantTypeB>, List<DialogListItem>>(
        _participantsA, _participantsB
    ) { participantsA, participantsB ->
        val sender = _sender.value

        ...
        ...
        
        return@CombinedLiveData ...
    }
val receiverListItems: LiveData<List<DialogListItem>>
    get() = _receiverListItems
```

When a new value is posted by doing `_sender.postValue(selectedSender)`, `_receiverListItems` should be  notified of that change. However, when I log the value of the `_sender`, I get `null`. How can I get `_receiverListItems` value dependent on `_sender` value?

Comment: What is CombinedLiveData class?

Comment: @TheLibrarian custom class for MediatorLiveData implementation

Comment: Ok, without details of CombinedLiveData, there is not much anyone can tell because it's not direct/exact sub-implementation of MediatorLiveData.

Comment: I believe we can ignore the CombinedLiveData part. What I have is a list of receivers which should be updated when a sender is selected (if user selects a sender from country A for example, I want to filter the list to include only receivers from country A and its neighbors).

Comment: The filtering part is done, but I cannot get the ```receiverListItems``` notified of the ```_sender``` value change

Comment: Look, if CombinedLiveData is already MediatorLiveData, then just another source for the source. (That's what `switchMap`(take one live data and create new live data with that value) actually is but without the boilerplate).

Comment: If `sender` is one of the `LiveData`s that needs to be watched, then it needs to be added as a source (through `MediatorLiveData#addSource`) so it can be observed. Right now it looks like your code is just observing those `participants` sources, and when one of *those* updates it directly reads from `sender.value` (which could be *null*, since it has no value initially). Can't know for sure without seeing your implementation, but what you've posted suggests that's what you're doing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a custom implementation of LiveData, this answer might be limited in what it says due to that but in general, you want `Transformation.switchMap`.

```
private val _receiverListItems: LiveData<List<DialogListItem>> =
    Transformation.switchMap(sender).map { sender -> 
        CombinedLiveData<
            List<ParticipantTypeA>, List<ParticipantTypeB>, List<DialogListItem>
        >(
            _participantsA, 
            _participantsB
        ) { participantsA, participantsB ->
           ...
           ...        
        return@CombinedLiveData ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I get Type mismatch error: Required: ```MutableLiveData<List<DialogListItem>>``` Found: ```LiveData<List<DialogListItem>!>```

Comment: @KhalidaAliyeva It might have been just because the variable type. I updated it